# Transfer pimcore site to another server

Tags: transfer, pimcore

Hy,

I am really new to Pimcore (I'm a joomla guy) and my friend asked me if I could help him transfer a page based on Pimcore to another server. I made a sql dump and copied all the files from the server to my hd and after that on the new server, imported the sql database, changed the username in the db and copied all the files back on the server. Also I made the correct changes for the db in the system.xml file in the config folder. But now all I get is a blank screen but the backend works partially (I can't see the files and the page). I would really appreciate some help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Several things could go wrong, but start with checking:

- MySQL user has access to the imported views. This is quite a common issue when importing views between servers,
- Apache Linux user has read/write access to the whole **website/var** folder, access to **/var/config** is not enough. Pimcore writes cache files to **website/var/cache** for example.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `mod_rewrite` in apache, or your vhost does not allow override.